# Change text or string to Arc Shape

Tags: text, rounding, shapes, automatic-ref-counting, circular-dependency

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScnPu.jpg)this is my code and i want it to be more arc shape like the image below

ub.data.textShapeArcConfiguration = {
curve: 800,
offset_y: -1000,
text_height: 1600,
bottom: 1600,
font_size: 450, // Increase the font size here
start_angle: -50,
end_angle: 50,
letter_spacing: 5,
text_rotation: -15
}

ub.data.textShapeArcConfiguration = {
curve: 800,
offset_y: -1000,
text_height: 1600,
bottom: 1600,
font_size: 450, // Increase the font size here
start_angle: -50,
end_angle: 50,
letter_spacing: 5,
text_rotation: -15
}
i try this code but it doesnt give me the text arc shape